# learning js/jquery trying to create a start button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Taking a class on js/jquery and the game works fine but you have to refresh the page to restart it.  I'm trying to create a button and have it "restart the game" but I just can't get it to work.

Any help/resources/advice would be appreciated thanks!!!

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Snake Game</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js'></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src='js/script.js'></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="row-md-6 row-md-offset-3">
            <h1>The Snake Game!!</h1>
            <canvas class='snake-game' width ='600px' height='500px'></canvas>
            <button type='button' class='start'>Start Game</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

js/jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var snakeCanvas = $('canvas.snake-game')[0],
    context = snakeCanvas.getContext('2d'),
    width = snakeCanvas.width,
    height = snakeCanvas.height,
    snakeSize = 10,
    snake = [
        { 'x': 0,'y': 0 },
        { 'x': 1, 'y': 0 },
        { 'x': 2, 'y': 0 },
        { 'x': 3, 'y': 0 },
        { 'x': 4, 'y': 0 },
        ],
        direction = 'right',
        gameSpeed = 50,
        score = 0;

    var foodX,
        foodY,
        gameLoop

    start();

    $('.start')on('click', function(){
        start();
    })
    function createNewFood(){
        foodX = parseInt(Math.random() * width/snakeSize);
        foodY = parseInt(Math.random() * yeah itheight/snakeSize);
    }

    function checkCollision(snakeArrayInput, foodXinput, foodYinput){
        var collision = 'nothing';

        snakeArrayInput.every(function(element){
          if(element.x == foodXinput && element.y == foodYinput){
            collision = "food";
            return false;
          }else if(element.x == -1 ||
                   element.y == -1 ||
                   element.x == width/snakeSize ||
                   element.y == height/snakeSize){
            collision = "wall";
            return false;
          }else{
            return true;
          }
        });

        return collision;
  }

    paint(0, 0, width, height, 'white', 'black');

    function start(){
        createNewFood();
        gameLoop = setInterval(reDraw, gameSpeed);    
    }

    function stop(){
        clearInterval(gameLoop);
    }



    function reDraw(){
        drawBg();
        drawSnake(snake);
        drawFood();
        drawScore();
        //checkCollision(snakeArrayInput, foodXinput, foodYinput);
        var collisionStatus = checkCollision(snake, foodX, foodY);
        if(collisionStatus == 'food'){
            score ++;
            createNewFood();
            snake.unshift(updateDirection(snake, direction));
        } else if (collisionStatus == 'wall'){
            stop();
            alert('Your score was: ' + score);
            score = 0;

        }
    };

    function drawFood(){
        paint(foodX*snakeSize, foodY*snakeSize, snakeSize, snakeSize, 'green', 'black');
    }

    function drawScore(){
        context.fillStyle = 'grey';
        context.fillText('Score: ' + score, width-596, height-6);
    }

    function drawBg(){
        paint(0,0,width, height, 'white', 'black');
    }

    function drawSnake(snakeInput){
        updateSnake(snakeInput);
        snakeInput.forEach(function(element){
            paint(element.x*10, element.y*10, snakeSize, snakeSize, 'orange', 'black');
        });

    }

    function paint(x, y, w, h, bgColor, borderColor){
        context.fillStyle = bgColor;
        context.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
        context.strokeStyle = borderColor;
        context.strokeRect(x, y, w, h);
    }

    function updateSnake(snakeInput){
    snakeInput.shift();
    snakeInput.push(updateDirection(snakeInput, direction));
    }

    function updateDirection(snakeInput, direction){
        var cellX = snakeInput[snakeInput.length-1].x;
        var cellY = snakeInput[snakeInput.length-1].y;

        if(direction == 'right'){
            cellX = cellX + 1;
        } else if (direction == 'left') {
            cellX = cellX - 1;
        } else if (direction == 'top') {
            cellY = cellY - 1;
        } else if (direction == 'bottom') {
            cellY = cellY + 1;
        }

        return {'x':cellX, 'y':cellY};
    }

    $(document).on('keydown', function(e){
        if(e.which == '37' && direction != 'right'){ // left keydown
          direction = 'left';
        }else if(e.which == '38' && direction != 'bottom'){ // top keydown
          direction = 'top';
        }else if(e.which == '39' && direction != 'left'){ // right keydown
          direction = 'right';
        }else if(e.which == '40' && direction != 'top'){ // bottom keydown
          direction = 'bottom';
        }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.start')on('click', function(){
        start();
    })
```

Missing dot, change to `$('.start').on('click', function(){`

```
function createNewFood(){
        foodX = parseInt(Math.random() * width/snakeSize);
        foodY = parseInt(Math.random() * yeah itheight/snakeSize);
    }
```

Change `foodY = parseInt(Math.random() * yeah itheight/snakeSize);` to 
`foodY = parseInt(Math.random() * height/snakeSize);`

Edit: So if you want start game to set to a playable state, you need to reinit your game parameters, here's the changes:

```
function start(){
    // Set init states.
    snakeSize = 10,
    snake = [
    { 'x': 0,'y': 0 },
    { 'x': 1, 'y': 0 },
    { 'x': 2, 'y': 0 },
    { 'x': 3, 'y': 0 },
    { 'x': 4, 'y': 0 },
    ],
    direction = 'right',
    gameSpeed = 50,
    score = 0;
    createNewFood();
    gameLoop = setInterval(reDraw, gameSpeed);    
}
```

Fixed it, and that works, and start game DO restart a playable game.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tsea8v45/3/)

Comment: Thank you for that.  Unfortunately when you click the start button the snake doesn't get reset the game just immediately has him run into the wall again..  That was the initial problem I was having and it still seems to exist even in your jsfiddle link.

Comment: Fixed it, please check.

Comment: Ugh, It was edited after your first command, anyway, if the answer you accept, click the checkmark next to it. This lets people know that your question has been solved. And, try to use online code template like jsfiddle, jsbin or even the snippet provided by SO itself, so we can find out  the problem faster.

Comment: Also, it prevents your typo on provided code template, which I believe first 2 issues I solved, may highly possible to be merely a typo.